# Google Drive API V3 in my windows services

Tags: .net, api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API V3 in my windows services, which is working fine at my local system, but when i am going to deploy it the API authentication process is not working. i am not getting any response from api.

BELOW IS MY CODE

```
 string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, 
 DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata };


        credPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);


        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
        scopes,
        "saurabh.katiyar",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;


        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName
        });
```

Comment: var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
        scopes,
       Environment.UserName,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the sample [.net](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) code in the documentation:

Compare your code from the given sample.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DriveQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = {  DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

For further reading, you can check [Authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#authentication-and-authorization).